# SQL Server : Update reporting table in real time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

For one of our applications we have huge data in multiple tables and every time a user does something new record is inserted in to these tables. There is a reporting screen where we have to do calculations from these tables and show the total from these tables

For example: Assume two parent tables Employee and Attendance
Employee table has 100,000 records and Attendance table has data for each day whenever a employee goes and comes out of their building. The records in Attendance table is more 2 million for one year. I need to calculate the attendance for each employee (Total) and display it on screen for all 100,000 records and it is paginated based on employee name. The caluclation takes too much time and it spikes the DB CPU.

To avoid runtime calculation for the total Im planning to have a separate table with total calculated values for each employee and just query the table and show it whenever needed. But the problem is for previous years the data is not going to change but for the current year the data will be generated whenever the employee records attendance day to day. What is the best option for me to keep the table updated in real time with Total for every employee whenever new attendance is recorded for the current year.

I thought of using triggers but triggers are synchronous and it should affect the performance of my reporting application when ever I query or it will affect the performance of inserts into parent table.

Please let me know if there are any better ways to update my Total value table in real time without impacting the performance of insert or update to parent tables

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for indexed views. Certainly, the core of your query is a group by such as:

```
select EmployeeID, count(*)
from AttendanceRecords
group by EmployeeID
```

Index that view. It's contents will then be available cheaply and updated in real time. There is zero potential for out-of-sync data.

Comment: This might be a good solution, but make sure it doesn't affect your insert performance.  I have seen indexed views really drag things down with inserts, replication, etc...

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF yeah. He needs to review the query plans. Properly done it's really just like another index. Not a lot more expensive than that. The delta update logic of the engine is sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use SQL Change Tracking:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb933875.aspx

This is not change data capture (which can be quite heavy) - change tracking just lets you know which keys changed so you can act on it.  With that information, you could have a regular job that collects those changes and updates your summaries.

...or, if you can use SQL 2014, you could get into Updatable Column Stores and dispense with the summaries.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider exporting data from previous years and using it to create the total attendance counts for employees in earlier years?

You say you're moving towards essentially having a table acting as a counter at the moment, so by ensuring your old data conforms to this model as well it'll be much easier to write and maintain the code that interacts with it and server load from any individual query should be minimal.